# Network manager auto-connect to wifi-network fails

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

Network manager (nm) does not auto-connect to a configured wifi-network (e.g. "net-a") after upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10. Before the upgrade nm auto-connected to the pre-configured wireless network (net-a). Now you have to manually connect to the configured wifi-network (net-a). After manual connect, the network performes normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded to 13.10 and I couldn't figure it out either. So I went to the internet and did some research and found a command that resets the network services. Type in this command: `sudo service network-manager restart`. This command stops my network connection and reconnects automatically, like it should. I have since upgraded my kernel manually and I have not had this issue since (might be a coincidence).

Good luck!

~Gomeazy

Comment: A simple restart of the network manager did not fix the issue. The problem occurs after each reboot. Upgrading the kernel manually is not an option.